# Scale image fixed amount based on highest of width or height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div called "photoFrame" that will contain images.
photoFrame has a width of 450px and a height of 350px;

I have images that vary in size.

What I want to be able to do is determine if a particular image is 1) wider than it is tall or 2) taller than it is wide. Once I have this, I want to resize the image to be either width:450px;height:auto; or width:auto;height350px;

I am doing this now with javascript, but was wondering if there were a better way of doing this through css, or jquery?

**EDIT:**

I am replacing the old code with the jquery.cycle.lite plug-in.

I have added this into the $.fn.cycle function (though I would prefer not to):

```
$slides.each(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    if($el.width() > $el.height()){ $el.css('width',450); } // Custom coding here
    else{ $el.css('height',350); }
    ...
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

Just for reference, here is the final modification..it resizes the image and centers it either horizontally or vertically within the photoFrame div.

```
$slides.each(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    if($el.width() > $el.height()){  // Custom coding here
        $el.css('width',450); 
        if($el.height() != 350){ // Account for height equal to photoFrame height
            $el.css('top','50%');
            $el.css('margin-top',-($el.height() / 2));
        }
    }else{ 
        $el.css('height',350); 
        if($el.width != 450){ // Account for width equal to photoFrame width
            $el.css('left','50%');
            $el.css('margin-left',-($el.width() / 2));
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Good to see you got something that works. If you've figured out a solution to your own problem, you can (and should!) add it as an answer instead of editing it into the question. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

Modified jquery.cycle.lite.js so that it resized the images it cycles through to fit the dimensions of the photoFrame div.

**$.fn.cycle**

```
$slides.each(function(){ 
    var $el = $(this); 
    if($el.width() > $el.height()){  // Custom coding here 
        $el.css('width',450);  
        if($el.height() != 350){ // Account for height equal to photoFrame height 
            $el.css('top','50%'); 
            $el.css('margin-top',-($el.height() / 2)); 
        } 
    }else{  
        $el.css('height',350);  
        if($el.width != 450){ // Account for width equal to photoFrame width 
            $el.css('left','50%'); 
            $el.css('margin-left',-($el.width() / 2)); 
        } 
    } 
    ... 
});
```